# How to send a post request using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using POSTMAN to send the post api request and it is working fine. I had to send a JSON RAW

```
{
    "id": "232",
    "message": "elele",
    "authorName": "JK Rowling"
}
```

and I am getting a successful response. But I want to send the post request from the User interface and it is not working.

This is the ThymeLeaf processing error:

```
"Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
```

This is the html part of it:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/api/v1/greetings}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{message}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

This is the controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/greetings")
public class GreetingController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Create Greeting", notes = "Create a greeting based on the given input")
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<GreetingResponse> create(@Valid @RequestBody GreetingRequest greetingRequest) {
    //
    }
```

and this is the class:

```
public class Greeting {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

@Column(name = "message")
String message;

@Column(name = "author_name")
String authorName;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I dont see Content-Type header `Content-Type: application/json` being passed. Maybe that could be the issue. Try passing that.

Comment: Please check network traffic and see what error you are getting there?

Comment: You cut off your error message. Always post _the entire stack trace_. Note that it's unusual (though not always wrong) to use `ResponseEntity` with an HTML controller. The fact that you have `@ApiOperation` suggests that you may be unclear as to whether you're doing page-load POST or AJAX POST.

Comment: A form isn't a json request body. Those are different things.

Comment: Do you want to receive a form or json? In the latter case use JavaScript to submit your form as JSON and handle the result, in the former case, replace `@RequestBody` with `@ModelAttribute`. Also `ResponseEntity` isn't usable than you would need to render a view. All in all it seems you are missing some of the basics.